Count calendar folder items after applying IncludeRecurrences=true
I have been trying to get this working without success so here is my question. The problem is that when applying
dynamic calItems = folder.Items;

string filter = "[Start] >='" + startDate + "' and [End] <= '" + endDate + "' And  [IsRecurring]  = True ";

calItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;
calItems.Sort("[Start]", Type.Missing);
dynamic recurringItems = calItems.Restrict(filter);
int totalRecurringAppointments = recurringItems.Count;

I am getting totalRecurringAppointments as 2147483647 when applying recurringItems.Count which is not correct as it is int max value. Dates are correct in my filter string as below they are working fine.
This is working, but looping is very slow
dynamic calItems = folder.Items;
string filter = "[Start] >='" + startDate + "' and [End] <= '" + endDate + "'";
dynamic calendarAppointments = calItems.Restrict(filter);
int totalCalendarAppointments = 0;

foreach (var item in calendarAppointments)
{
  totalCalendarAppointments++;
}

Is there some better way of getting all calendar items including recurring ones. I would like to find some solution without need of using loop.

2147483647 means OOM does not know without doing what your loop does - look at each and every potential match and check if it qualifies. Each potential match still needs to be checked: what if it has an exception (modified or deleted) for a particular instance?

This means the one and only possible way is to use loop? I was wondering maybe there is some solution to get total amount of items in Calendar folder then somehow identify which have recurring setting on and count these recurrances for each item or some other solution using Outlook query inside filter string?

No, Outlook has to first (1) use a query on the folder basis (similar to your query) to figure out if there are potential matches - appointments that fall within the given range based on their start/end times, and then (2)  retrieve the recurrence blob from all potential matches (it is possible to do that without opening the appointments directly) and see if it recurrence pattern produces a match and then (3) refine to check if any exceptions (modified or deleted) make the appointment a match or a mismatch.
